# Is it possible to use TX as RX pin?

Tags: raspbian

I would like to connect two air quality sensors with UART. I'm only using RX pin to read values from sensor. Is it possible to use TX pin on Rasp Pi 3 as normal RX?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This usage is not supported by the Linux drivers.

You could of course set the TX GPIO to INPUT mode and bit bang a serial link on that GPIO.  The lower the baud rate you use the more likely this is to work.

(My) pigpio supports software serial links.  You could test the device with the following commands from the command line.  The example assumes your device communicates at 9600, change accordingly.

```
sudo pigpiod        # start the pigpio daemon.

pigs slro 14 9600 8 # use GPIO 14 (TXD) to receive 8-bit data at 9600bps

pigs slr 14 1000    # read up to 1000 characters from GPIO 14
```

See [SLRO](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#SLRO) and [SLR](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#SLR).

Comment: I would assume that the available UART peripheral functions is limited on a per-pin basis in the SoC. That is, this isn't a driver limitation but a hardware limitation of peripheral multiplexing, no?

Comment: @crasic Correct, the Pi only has UART support on a few GPIO.  However the Linux driver did not (perhaps still does not) support all the UART GPIO (in particular those only exposed on the Compute Module).